# Relation between global and local basis functions in finite element methods

Tags: polynomials, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain
- $\mathcal T$ be a finite set of compact subsets of $\mathbb R^d$ with $$\stackrel{\circ}K_1\cap\stackrel{\circ}K_2=\emptyset\;\;\;\text{for all }K_1,K_2\in\mathcal T\tag1$$ and $$\overline\Lambda=\bigcup_{K\in\mathcal T}K\tag2$$
- $r_K\in\mathbb N$ and $\mathcal P_K\subseteq\mathbb R^K$ be a $r_K$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector space, for $K\in\mathcal T$
- $\mathcal N_K=\left\{N^K_1,\ldots,N^K_{r_K}\right\}$ be a basis of $\mathcal P_K^\ast$, for $K\in\mathcal T$
- $\left\{\phi^K_1,\ldots,\phi^K_{r_K}\right\}$ be the basis of $\mathcal P_K$ dual to $\mathcal N_K$, i.e. $$N^k_i(\phi^K_j)=\delta_{ij}\;\;\;\text{for all }i,j\in\left\{1,\ldots,r_K\right\}\;,\tag3$$ for $K\in\mathcal T$

Now, let $$V:=\left\{v\in C^0(\overline\Lambda):\left.v\right|_{K}\in\mathcal P_K\text{ for all }K\in\mathcal T\right\}\;.$$

> Let $(\phi_i)_{i\in I}$ with $I\subseteq\mathbb N$ and $|I|<\infty$ be a basis of $V$. How are the $\phi_i$ related to the $\phi_j^K$?

In the context of finite element methods, the $\phi_i$ are called *global basis functions* and the $\phi_j^K$ are called *local basis functions*. In practice, it's clear how exactly the $\phi_j^K$ are defined by the choice of $(\mathcal P_K,\mathcal N_K)$. However, the Galerkin solution is expressed in terms of the $\phi_i$ and I haven't found how they need to be defined in any lecture note or book.

If necessary, we may assume that $\mathcal P_K$ is a space of polynomials $K\to\mathbb R$. See also [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183825/global-basis-functions-in-the-finite-element-method).

Answer (score 2):

Without proper gluing conditions, there is no hope to get sensible relations between global and local basis functions.

For instance, let $\Lambda$ be an open interval split into open intervals $K$. 
For $K=(a,b)$ define the only local basis function $\phi^K:=x-a$. Then $\{N^K\}$ with $N^K(\phi)=\phi(b)$ is a basis of $P_K^*$. According to your definition of $V$, it holds $V=\{0\}$. So there is no global basis function at all.

I recommend reading Chapter 2 in Ciarlet's (old) book on finite element methods. There the construction of the global space from local elements is explained in detail.

Comment: In the book you've mentioned, the the relation is described on page 93. The author takes a functional $\phi_h$ from the "degrees of freedom of the finite element space", a node $b$ and any finite element $K_\lambda$ for which $b$ is a node. Then he considers "the basis function $p_\lambda$ of the finite element $K_\lambda$ associated with the restriction of $\phi_h$ to $K_\lambda$" ... I have no clue what's meant by "associated with the restriction". Do you know it? Which of the local basis function in $K_\lambda$ is $p_\lambda$?

Comment: $\phi_h$ is the global degree of freedom. It is associated to some local degree of freedom $\phi_b$ (e.g. evaluation at the node of a triangle). Then the associated $p_\lambda$ is the local function such that $\phi_b(p_\lambda)=1$ and $\psi(p_\lambda)=0$  for all other local degrees of freedom (e.g. $p_\lambda$ is a  local hat function).

Comment: $\phi_b$ and $\phi_h$ are in principle the same functionals, namely evaluation at the same node $b$. The  difference is, that the first is for functions on $\Omega$, the second for functions on $K$. Hope this helps. It is rather complicated to formulate these FE spaces in such abstract way. It helps to imagine piecewise linear functions and evaluation functionals at node.